# Attaching and then storing it in table. Ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have developed a functionality in MS Access to attach pictures in a form and then storing it in a table. But as I have different users and I want them to attach pictures and then store those attachments in a table in the same application but I want those attachments to be attached in user's wise ie in different rows of the table.

Below is a screenshot for what I have done.

[image]

Below is the code that I have written

```
Option Compare Database

'Public Function SaveAttachments(strPath As String, Optional strPattern As
'String = "*.*") As Long
'Public Function LoadAttachments(strPath As String, Optional strPattern As i
'String = "*.*") As Long

Public Function LoadAttachments()
'(strPath As String, Optional StrPattern As String) As Long

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim fld As DAO.Field2
    Dim strFile As String

    'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblAttachments")
    Set fld = rst("Fieldatttachment")

    'Navigate through the table
    Do While Not rst.EOF

       'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
        Set rsA = fld.Value

        'Load all attachments in the specified directory
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.*")

        rst.Edit
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0    
            'Add a new attachment that matches the pattern.
            'Pass "" to match all files.
            If strFile Like StrPattern Then
                rsA.AddNew
                rsA("FileData").LoadFromFile strPath & "\" & strFile
                rsA.Update

                'Increment the number of files added
                LoadAttachments = LoadAttachments + 1
            End If
            strFile = Dir
        Loop

        'Save all attachments in the field    
        If rsA("FileName") Like StrPattern Then
                strFullPath = strPath & "\" & rsA("FileName")

        rsA.Close

        rst.Update
        'Next record
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rsA = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Fieldatttachment_Click()
    Call LoadAttachments
End Sub
```

Comment: As is this code cannot be run. You reference *LoadAttachments* (the name of function) but never initialized it with a data type. Plus, you have an un-closed `If` block. However, do note: `End if` is not needed if `If` statement is one line.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field, UserId, to the table.

Filter on the user's ID when opening the form.

Fill this field (by default) with the user's ID whenever a record is created/inserted.

Design your application to normally hide tables so the users don't have direct access to tables.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a *UserId* field to table and then passing it from the form as a parameter to function, *LoadAttachments* where you filter the recordset with a `WHERE` clause. Notice I rendered function a return-able object by assigning it a data type.

```
Public Function LoadAttachments(useridparam As Integer) As Long
'(strPath As String, Optional StrPattern As String) As Long

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim fld As DAO.Field2
    Dim strFile As String

    'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblAttachments WHERE UserID=" & useridparam)
    Set fld = rst("Fieldatttachment")

    '...same logic (syntax fixed)...

End Function

Private Sub Fieldatttachment_Click()
    Dim result As Long

    result = LoadAttachments(Forms!frmAttachments!UserId)

    Msgbox "Successfully uploaded " & result & " files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL UPLOAD"
End Sub
```